# win 16 subsystem has insufficient resources

Tags: windows

I encountered the message

> The win16 subsystem has insufficient
>   resources to continue running. Click
>   on OK, close your application and
>   restart your machine

on PC after running 15 minutes of running a program called  `WinTariff`. So I often restart the PC to run that program. That program is used to collect and process information telephone calls.

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: WinTarrif is *old* if it's still the 16-bit version. I suspect it's got some sort of memory leak, or is generally incompatible with modern OS's. Something to try might be installing Windows 3.11 on a virtual machine and passing through the COM port to the VM in order to run the software. I know it's around-about and a bit complex, but it should work. The other option is to get a newer version.

Answer (score 1):

The ideal thing to do would be to upgrade the application to a 32 bit version but I'm almost prepared to bet you don't have that option. The only thing I can suggest, and the only thing that has ever helped me with the same situation, is to increase your virtual memory (paging file) and to set it to a fixed size. As a general rule it should be set to between 2 and 4 times the physical memory. If you can add additional RAM to the machine that may also help.

Answer (score 1):

Virtual memory has nothing to do with this message. The problem is with GDI handles.

See this page: http://www.vttoth.com/wow32.htm